# IOS Image Upload in background thread, even in app background state

Tags: ios, multithreading, image, background, upload

**REQUIREMENT**
I want to upload images in a background thread, multiple images in IOS, even when app goes to background state.
**QUESTION**
 1. How to do this?
 2. Will Apple reject these kind of behaviour in APP STORE
**NOTES**
This is for an existing app update, which was there for like 3 years and 100,000+ users

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: No I did not find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete document on handling background downloading, you can make changes as per your upload requests.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background

Comment: I need to know about Uploading, not downloading

Comment: you can tweak the download code for upload request.. Just the request would change..

Comment: problem is apple will reject those